# Automatically update value with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

i'm new using JS so i'm having problems here rsrs

i need to automatically update the result field, as soon as the user starts to insert the value on amount's field

```
$(document).ready ->
$('form').submit ->
if $('form').attr('action') == '/convert'
  $.ajax '/convert',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'json'
      data: {
              source_currency: $("#source_currency").val(),
              target_currency: $("#target_currency").val(),
              amount: $("#amount").val()
            }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        alert textStatus
      success: (data, text, jqXHR) ->
        $('#result').val(data.value)
    return false;
```

right now i have a submit button that calls the /convert
but how can i erase it and just call the API just when i receive the value, incompleted or not

```
   class ExchangeService
  def initialize(source_currency, target_currency, amount)
    @source_currency = source_currency
    @target_currency = target_currency
    @amount = amount.to_f
  end


def call
    value = get_exchange
    value * @amount
  rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => e
    e.response
  end

def get_exchange
  exchange_api_url = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:currency_api_url]
  exchange_api_key = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:currency_api_key]
  url = "#{exchange_api_url}?token=#{exchange_api_key}&currency=#{@source_currency}/#{@target_currency}"
  result = RestClient.get url
  JSON.parse(result.body)['currency'][0]['value'].to_f
end
end
```

Comment: You can use remote: true in your form and skip and code of AJAX, and after that use an view like .js.erb to append your data.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get it, can you pls give an example?

Comment: Yes I will make an answer at the bottom

Comment: You can listen to the `input` or the `change` events from your input element and use that to trigger the AJAX request. `$('#my-input').on 'input', ->` instead of `$('form').submit ->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [remote: true](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers) from Rails to make AJAX request:

A simple example with a Car resources:

cars_controller.rb

```rb
def create
  @car = Car.new(car_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @car.save
      format.js
    else
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: car, local: false) do |form| %>
  <% if car.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(car.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this car from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% car.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```js
console.log('<%= @car.name  %>');
```

So, when you submit your rails form, the request will make like JS. Your controller needs to accept this format(format.js) and when the data are processed by the controller the flow continues to the action but with js extension(create.js.erb) in this file you can make what you want, append data, replace data, change values and can use Ruby + JS
I hope it serves you, forgive my bad English